# Mysql "ON UPDATE" constraint deletes my row

Tags: mysql, delete-row, onupdate

I have a problem with my DB (InnoDB). I have two tables:

```
    table1{
    id1 INT..
    ..
    PRIMARY KEY (id1)
    }

    table2{
    fk INT..
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (FK) REFERENCES table1(id1)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    }
```

Now...when I change a record into table1 the records in table2 are deleted! I don't want this behavior. How can I change this?

I read that "InnoDB allows a foreign key constraint to reference a non-unique key". My key is unique. How can I change this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour since the foreign key in `table2` is defined with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` property. Deletes in `table1` are "cascaded to" `table2`.

You may want to [change this definition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Comment: Yes. I know, but the row will be delete also when I update in table1. I don't know why.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I read too fast. Then there must be something else taking place (a trigger on `table1` ?). What happens here cannot be related to the foreign key (unless you use `REPLACE` instead of `UPDATE` to "change a record in `table1`", since `REPLACE` is actually a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT`).

Comment: Yes. A trigger. This trigger change a number into another table.
No...I use UPDATE

Comment: Follow this lead! Perhaps this trigger triggers another trigger in cascade.

Comment: No. I have other triggers but it's impossible that this are triggered. Because into my trigger I update a single row into table3, and there isn't any trigger for my table3.

Comment: There [**must** be something else](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8ac/2). Does this happen even if you issue the `UPDATE` statement directly from the console?

Comment: I have a lot of tables linked each other. So it's difficult to explain all the DB.
Imagine a table for bills, another table for each row of the bill.

Comment: There is a debugger into mysql? I would see all my queries. It's possible?

Comment: No debugger that I know of. The [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html) logs all incoming queries (but will not log triggers activity).

Comment: Ok. Anyway I have found the problem. Is not an sql problem but other queries into PHP!
Thank you!